# structure map injection only works in ApplicationController : IController And Not Work in a Class

Tags: configuration, structuremap, setter, code-injection

My Problem With StructureMap Injection From ServiceLayer.Intefaces Of My Project

MyProject
UI
 1.MVC5 WebApplication
ServiceLayer
 1.interfaces
 2.Services
DataLayer
 1.SiteContext
 2.Configuration(migrations)
DomainClasses
 1.Models

in UI - MVC5 :
Install From Nuget : StructureMap.MVC5

and All Works When use like This:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IPaymentService PaymentService { get; set; }
    public IIdentityManagerService IdentityManagerService { get; set; }
    public IApplicationGroupService ApplicationGroupService { get; set; }
    public IApplicationUserService ApplicationUserService { get; set; }
    public IUnitOfWork _UoW { get; set; }}
```

But Not Work Out of Controller , Like This:

```
public class CustomStartup
{
    public IIdentityManagerService IdentityManagerService { get; set; }
    public IApplicationGroupService ApplicationGroupService { get; set; }
    public IApplicationUserService ApplicationUserService { get; set; }
}
```

My Project StructureMap Configuration :

See This : [image]

AND When Use Injection From CustomStratup get This Error:

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ServiceLayer.Interfaces.IIdentityManagerService'
>   There is no configuration specified for ServiceLayer.Interfaces.IIdentityManagerService
>   1.) Container.GetInstance(ServiceLayer.Interfaces.IIdentityManagerService)

Please Help Me to Fix this Problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. It's a little bit strange situation. You can try to clearly define property. It works for me:

```
public class CustomStartup
{
    public IIdentityManagerService IdentityManagerService 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.Container.GetInstance<IIdentityManagerService>();
        } 
    }
}
```

And while I'm looking for a more elegant solution :)